# Can someone know that I'm using a VPN if they have my MAC address?

Tags: vpn

My university has a web filter, so I use a VPN to access blocked sites. They also have my MAC address. Can they identify that I'm using a VPN and what I'm doing on the internet?

Comment: Do they have an actual rule against using VPNs?

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is yes.
They can see that you have used ports that are using for vpn services and they can see the encrypted traffic between you and the vpn provider.